# Eclipse doesn't find jdk

Tags: java, eclipse, raspberry-pi

So I asked this on RaspberryPiExchange but someone there told me to ask here so here it is.

I recently had to reinstall Rasbian on my Raspberry Pi due do something becoming corrupt and apt-get not working. I made sure to backup what I could before I reinstalled. So when I went to reinstall Eclipse and pickup where I left off in one of my Java projects it was very worrying when Java keywords weren't highlighted. I've tried googling to figure out if I skipped a step but it does seem I have. I'm running Jessie 8 with jdk8 that came preinstalled assuming it's the same one you'd get from doing apt-get install. So my question is can anyone help me figure out why it seems Eclipse no longer recognizes Java as a whole. Also, I would like to mention I have already installed the Eclipse Java Development plugin.Here is a screenshot of just a few lines to better show what I'm trying to say Screenshot of an example program [screenshot of eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDNO6.png)

Comment: Try this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_6mnQ2LlhIc

Comment: Well its weird because I just connected to my raspberry pi via a sudo vnc session and there eclipse seems fine so Im gonna fiddle around with it for a while if I find the answer I post it here

Comment: I did forget to mention without sudo vnc I dont even have the open to make a new java project

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after updating eclipse using the sudo vnc session when I went back over to the regular vnc session eclipse now finds all java related things